# Regex Chat Message detection

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently trying to develop a software to properly look at WhatsApp messages saved in .txt format (sent by e-mail) and am trying to make a parser.
I was trying around with Regex for the last 3 hours and haven't found a solution as I barely ever used Regex before.

Messages look like this:

```
16.08.2015, 18:30 - Person 1: Some multiline text here
still in the message
16.08.2015, 18:31 - Person 2: some other message which could be multiline
16.08.2015, 18:33 - Person 1: once again
```

I am trying to split them properly by matching with Regex
(like this)

```
List<string> messages = new List<string>();
messages = Regex.Matches(parseable, @"REGEXHERE").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

And they end up like this

```
messages[0]="16.08.2015, 18:30 - Person 1: Some multiline text here\nstill in the message";
messages[1]="16.08.2015, 18:31 - Person 2: some other message which could be multiline";
messages[2]="16.08.2015, 18:33 - Person 1: once again";
```

I've been trying with really messy regular expressions which looked something like `\d\d\\.\d\d\\. [...]`

Comment: What is your regex? Please post one. Do you just need to extract `16.08.2015, 18:30`, `16.08.2015, 18:31`, `16.08.2015, 18:33`?

Comment: Please edit your question as it is not clear how you want your messages to be parsed and where you are stuck.

Comment: *"I am trying to split them properly"* What do you consider "proper"? What is wrong with the output that you are getting? What output do you want?

Comment: OP, is it that you __want__ the messages to look like your last box, or that they do look like that and it's not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a single RegEx for this.  Instead, I'd just use a `StreadReader` or `StreamReader`; you have to check if the current line of processing is a "chat start" line (use a RegEx for that), and if so check if any of the following lines are not "chat start" lines, keeping track of whether you should be appending or yielding a new line.  I wrote up a quick extension method to demonstrate this:

```
public static class ChatReader
{
    static string pattern = @"\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d, \d\d:\d\d - .*?:";        
    static Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    static string prevLine = "";
    static string currLine = "";

    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadChatMessages(this TextReader reader)
    {
        prevLine = reader.ReadLine();
        currLine = reader.ReadLine();

        bool isPrevChatMsg = rgx.IsMatch(prevLine);                

        while (currLine != null)
        {
            bool isCurrChatMsg = rgx.IsMatch(currLine);
            if (isPrevChatMsg && isCurrChatMsg)
            {
                yield return prevLine;
                prevLine = currLine;                    
            }
            else if (isCurrChatMsg)
            {
                yield return currLine;
                prevLine = currLine;
            }
            else
            {
                prevLine += '\n' + currLine;
            }
            currLine = reader.ReadLine();

        }
        yield return prevLine;

    }
}
```

Can be used like:

```
List<string> chatMessages = reader.ReadChatMessages().ToList();
```